# macruby open() not working

Tags: file-io, macruby

The following example is, of course, not my entire app. I have provided the part of it that throws an error:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/macruby

require 'open-uri'
framework 'ScriptingBridge'

system "mkdir -p ~/.myApp"
system "cp ~/Desktop/image.png ~/.myApp/image.png"

var = open('~/.myApp/image.png', 'w')
```

The error is:

```
open: No such file or directory - open() failed (Errno::ENOENT)
```

Am I missing a library or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why but if you provide the path without using "~" it works.

Comment: I realized that too. I was wondering if there was someway to work around that, though. It is quite annoying. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`File.open File.expand_path('~/image.png'), 'w'`